# Improving my own question (now that I know more), or deleting it?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369399/zip-unzip-failing-throwing-multiple-exceptions-not-reproable) a couple days ago.  After a few days of working on the problem, we discovered that the underlying issue was a couple of flash drives with bad blocks (after being pulled out without being ejected) that were being used to transfer the data, and not with the code itself.  We likely wouldn't have noticed if we were working with uncompressed files.

So, while the issue wasn't software related, I feel like if I would have stumbled across a similar post with the same issue and same resolution in my initial searching, it would have saved me quite a bit of time (over 20 hours).

Should I delete this question, answer it myself, or is there something else I can do to improve it with our solution for future users with the same (or similar) issues?

Comment: I'd suggest answering it yourself. That way, future visitors can possibly get some useful information out of your experience.

Comment: @Cerbrus Given that the solution has nothing whatsoever to do with anything described in the question, I don't really see it being helpful to anyone else searching for solutions to that problem.  And I don't see how anyone else that did have the same problem with their drives would ever be finding this question when searching, given that it's describing problems not directly related to it.

Comment: @Servy that was my line of thought as well.  It seems to be a pretty specific case.  Granted... if anyone is copying .zip files to a usb drive programmatically, this issue is likely to arise again.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan You have a corrupted file.  There are *thousands* of ways that that could come up.  A bad drive is one (and one in which there are *many* subtle variations of).  Trying to have the question be, "I have a file that is corrupted, how did that happen?" is of course completely unanswerable as a question due to all of the possible reasons it could come up, and given that there's no way of distinguishing between them given the question.

Comment: Delete it -- If you improve, more people dv = question block; that's my experience here....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The question should be closed with the close reason stating:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

If you want to delete it yourself, that is probably worth doing given that the problem has nothing to do with anything described in the question, and as a result even if anyone else did ever have the same problem, they'd never find your question to get their solution.

Comment: I think there is still some value in the problem/solution combo.  Just not in its current form.  Is there anything I could do to keep the information available, but put it in a form that might be more useful?

Google hits for some of those errors resulted in VERY few results, making this a challenging issue to tackle.  I would have been happy for any lead.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan You wouldn't be making the google results for this problem any better by leaving this question around, for exactly the reasons I described in [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289208/improving-my-own-question-now-that-i-know-more-or-deleting-it/289210#comment171712_289208).  People will find your question when they have wildly different problems, and people with your problem aren't going to be finding your question.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'll be deleting the question.

Comment: I thought this close reason was for cases where the cause was never determined? Therefore if the problem mysteriously goes away then it is no longer reproduceable, and thus not answerable.  In this case the cause was found and the question/answer describes a symptom/cause pair that might be useful to others.  "Oh I get the same error, now I know file is possibly getting corrupted somehow."

Comment: I know you pointed out causes of corruption could be many, but the useful piece is not why it is corrupted, but that the symptom(particular exception/error) is potentially the result of corruption.  There certainly are some useful questions along the lines of TCP errors where a question about an obtuse error generates very enlightening answers about what causes such an error. One could make a strong case for whether or not we want a proliferation of such question/answers, since many will fall into troubleshooting strange PC issues, but sometimes they are useful for programming defensively.

Comment: @AaronLS The error message was "the file is corrupt".  The "answer" was why the file is corrupt.  There are *thousands* of ways for a file to be read as corrupt, and there is nothing in the question to really narrow that down.  The question, "what can cause a file to be corrupted" would be, if nothing else, *way* too broad to be answerable.  You could go on for days just describing all of the possible things that could cause a file to be corrupted.  There is no way for such a question to be on topic on SO.

Comment: @Servy There were four error messages and only one hinted at corruption, and that doesn't clarify that the corruption is likely external to the application. The answer doesn't need to list all possibilities to be useful. It is terribly worded, not in a way focused on the useful, in that in that it focuses on only one possibility, but it is useful to others that will realize that **in more general terms it's likely an issue causing corruption external to the program.**

Comment: @Servy Yes, you could try to list all the possible causes, but that would be a poor approach to answering the question.  It is not required to answer the question.   If someone asks "What makes a reptile distinct from a mammal?", you don't need to list all the traits a reptile has that a mammal does not and vice versa. You only need to point out the generalized traits that are key to classification.  The answer does a poor job of pointing out the classification of the problem as "an external corruption issue, not specific to your code", but could be reworded to be such an effective answer.

Comment: @AaronLS The code had four errors, two indicated that the file itself was inherently corrupt, and two were syntax errors in the file stemming from the fact that the file was corrupt.  If someone gets to this question because they had a syntax error in their file for any reason other than the file being corrupted, they'll just be sent on a wild goose chase.  If someone has a corrupt file, odds are that the specific syntax errors it results in will be entirely different each time, and they wouldn't find the question through that error.

Comment: @AaronLS If you're think that it's useful to see a question that says, "What does `A local file header is corrupt.` mean?" with an answer of, "The file is corrupt." I'm just not seeing how that's possibly useful.  It's just re-stating the error message right back at the question.  All of the information you're claiming would be useful to see in an answer is *already in the error message*.

Comment: @Servy "All of the information you're claiming would be useful to see in an answer is already in the error message." No it's not, show me where the error message says that it's possibly an external issue? I said "the corruption is likely external to the application" and "corruption external to the program".  It seems like you're ignoring that distinction for the sake of argument.  First instinct with an error message for less experienced programmers, or even experienced tired programmers, is to look for a cause of the error in their code. An answer that points out otherwise is useful.

Comment: @Servy Put yourself in the shoes of a programmer getting this error message. Similar code, that's valid code, but maybe the 1st time they've dealt with the API/code. They are doubting themselves because they can't get it to work, thinking their code causes the corruption. They search for that error message, find the question, and see "oh, maybe it's not my code after all, a potential issue is with corruption caused by device." It's not a wild goose chase to simply run the code against a different file location. It leads them to a simple troubleshooting step to confirm deny that as an issue.

Comment: @Servy Is it better that every time someone gets that error, that they post their code, thinking it's a code issue?  When instead they could have found this question/answer and already confirmed/denied that they've ruled that out as a possibility?  We need to encourage preserving history of troubleshooting, rather than encourage that information to be eliminated so that we end up holding each and every person's hand through the same discovery process.

Comment: @Servy I can't count the number of times we've had some really strange error or scenario, and between different questions on SO, we were able to troubleshoot the error, without ever having to reach out for help. Some question/answers didn't apply to our scenario, but between the possibilities we found one that applied. Did the existence of the information prevent us from posting a question, only to find that it was a non-code issue and something completely unrelated? Yes.

Comment: @Servy Would SO have been better off if those other questions had been deleted, thus leading us to assume it was a code issue, and post a question that would have ultimately led to the same information in a previously deleted question?  **Are you wanting to encourage hand-holding, instead of resourcefulness?**

Comment: @Servy While we're at it, let's delete all the question/answers that deal with SQL Server connection strings.  The possible causes of failed connections are numerous.  The error message usually points out the symptom, but not the potential cause, and your opinion is that is sufficient information. On one hand you say pointing out all the potential causes are too numerous to be useful, yet on the other hand you say the error message is sufficient.  **So if the error message is sufficient to point to the cause, why would you need to list out numerous causes?  Are the causes singular or plural?**

Comment: So let's delete that stuff, and everytime someone writes code against SQL Server and gets a connection exception, they can come here, and try to get people to hold their hand through the numerous possibilities, rather than being resourceful and looking through previous Q/A on the same issue.

Comment: @AaronLS So you're saying that it's worthwhile to post an answer that says, "the error message is actually correct, the file really is corrupted, and you weren't getting the error message incorrectly?"  Seriously?  You think it adds value to say that the error message quoted is isn't incorrectly reporting the problem?  Such an answer is useless.  Whether it's sufficient or not *it's adding zero value*.

Comment: I didn't say that repeating the error message answers the question, I said *seeing such an answer tells you nothing you didn't already know*.  If reading the error message *doesn't* answer your question, reading such an answer wouldn't either.  You're advocating keeping around content that contains zero useful information, that isn't ever going to help anyone find a solution to a problem they have.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @AaronLS.  I was back and forth between your viewpoint and Servy's.  That's why I asked this question.  Ultimately, in this case I didn't (and still don't) have a solid solution, and couldn't see a clear way to format my findings in a Q&A format appropriate for SO, so I wound up deleting the question.  It's certainly a little bit more complicated than "we have no idea why the files are corrupt", since we can now reproduce the errors.  I've penciled a post about my findings into my blog schedule, in case I can formulate them into something that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your own question, on the grounds that it's a nonreproduceable problem (in the terms of *that* question)... *and* ask another question designed to attract people with the "right" problem. Then you self-answer the second question. It will take more time, but everybody wins.

Also, the problem might attract further answers detailing other possible causes for your symptoms. Those wouldn't have helped you of course, but may well help others.